# Do I have to exit Visual Studio for Team Explorer to detect "Remove project" changes in my Solution.sln?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I have a solution and it's source controlled with Git and Team Services.

If the solution is empty and  I *add* a an existing project, everything works fine.
The solution gets a red mark on it, Team explorer detects changes in Solution.sln, and I can commit and push. Afterwards, the padlock is back next to the solutionand everything is fine.

However, if I now *remove* the project from the solution and saves the Solution.sln file, there is no red mark next to the solution and no change is detected in the Team Explorer. Hence I cannot commit and push my change.

To remedy this I need to exit Visual Studio and open the project again. The change is now detected and the solution has a red mark next to it. I can commit and push my change. The solution gets a padlock and all is well in the repository as well.

Is it desired behavior that one has to exit Visual Studio to detect *Remove project* changes?

Comment: Does a refresh on the "Changes" panel of Team Explorer help? This seems really odd. Also, what version of Visual Studio are you using RTM/Update 1/2?

Comment: Hi, fully updated and no detection if I refresh changes

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think it's desired behavior. I tested with VS 2015 update2, if I remove a project in a solution which have multiple projects, the solution will detect it. Please check the screenshots below:

1. two projects in a solution

[image]

2. remove one project

[image]

3. solution detect the change immediately

[image]

But if only have one project in the solution, I could reproduce your scenario. After removing the only project, you won't be able to see the solution either in Team Explorer. It seems the solution can't be detected in source control unless re-open VS.

I tested with a TFVC team project, which don't have this issue. I'd like to suggest you submit a feedback at website: connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio

Comment: Hi, does this work for you if you only have 1 project, not 2. You make a solution with one project and add/remove this project?

Comment: If only have one project, I could reproduce your scenario. I tested with a TFVC team project, don't have this issue. Please submit a feedback at website: http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio